# Casting results from Observable.forkJoin to their respective types in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Let say I have a component in Angular 2 that needs to load 2 different things from the server before the page is displayed.  I'd like all of those things to fire off and call one event handler when they come back telling the page isLoaded = true. Let's say I have a service class that looks like this.

```
export class MyService {
   getStronglyTypedData1(): Observable<StrongData1[]>{
      return this.http.get('http://...').map((response:Response) => <StrongData1[]>response.json());
   }
   getStronglyTypedData2(): Observable<StrongData2[]>{
         return this.http.get('http://...').map((response:Response) => <StrongData2[]>response.json());
   }
}
```

Then I have a component that uses that service class like this.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   isLoaded = false;
   stronglyTypedData1: StrongData1[];
   stronglyTypedData2: StrongData2[];

   constructor(private myService:MyService){ }

   ngOnInit(){
      var requests [ 
         this.myService.getStronglyTypedData1(),
         this.myService.getStronglyTypedData2()
      ];
      Observable.forkJoin(requests).subscribe(
         results => {
            this.stronglyTypedData1 = results[0];
            this.stronglyTypedData2 = results[1];
            this.isLoaded = true;
         });
   }
}
```

The TypeScript compiler is complaining that it cant convert type object to type StrongData1[]. If I change StrongData1 and StrongData2 to "any", everything works fine.  I'd rather not do that though because I'm losing the benefit of TypeScript's strong typings.

How do I cast the results from forkJoin to their respective types?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

for me it always works when i add the requests directly to the Observable.forkJoin and then use es6 destructing for the result array.

so your code could look like this

```
Observable
    .forkJoin(this.myService.getStronglyTypedData1(), this.myService.getStronglyTypedData2())
    .subscribe(
        ([typeData1, typeData2]) => {
            this.stronglyTypedData1 = typeData1;
            this.stronglyTypedData2 = typeData2;
            this.isLoaded = true;
        }
    );
```

Comment: The difference is when you use forkJoin to pass in an array you will get type checking error. You don't have to add the requests directly to the Observable.forkJoin. You can do `var request1 = this.myService.getStronglyTypedData1(); var request2 = this.myService.getStronglyTypedData2()` then `Observable.forkJoin(request1, request2).subscribe(results => { type1 = results[0]; type2 = results[1] })` or es6 destructing `Observable.forkJoin(request1, request2).subscribe(([type1, type2]) => { type1 = type1; type2 = type2})`

Comment: In case you're like me and you don't see it: don't pass in an array to `forkJoin([typedReq1, typedReq2])` , instead directly add the observables: `forkJoin(typedReq1, typedReq2)` and the ES6 destructing variables will be typed.

Comment: This appears to be deprecated in RxJs 6

Comment: With rxjs 6 you should directly use forkJoin import from rxjs instead of Observable.forkJoin

Answer (score 11):

In Typescript you can use destructuring on function parameters (a tuple in this case):

```
const requests = [ 
    this.myService.getStronglyTypedData1(),
    this.myService.getStronglyTypedData2()
];
forkJoin(requests)
    .subscribe(([data1, data2]: [StrongData1[], StrongData2[]]) => {
        this.stronglyTypedData1 = data1;
        this.stronglyTypedData2 = data2;
        this.isLoaded = true;
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

try

```
(results:[StrongData1[], StrongData2[]]) =>
```

Comment: it throw exception like "results must be StrongData1[]". you can write Array<StrongData1 | StrongData2> . But @Nicolas-Gehlert answer work fine.